# How to add/repeat the same widget on QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Next code displays just only `one` instance of the button;

```
VBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
QPushButton * btn1 = new QPushButton("1", this);

layout->addWidget(btn1);
layout->addWidget(btn1);
layout->addWidget(btn1);
```

But i expected it will be repeating 3 times;

Comment: You have to create new instances of `QPushButton` for each row. You cannot add same widget over and over.

Comment: With Qt you really don't need to keep all these pointers. You add widgets to your form and connect signals and slots. If you ever need the pointer you can use `form->find_child<QPushButton*>("nameOfChild");`  [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#findChild)

Comment: I see the question, the proposed answer below and the comments. I guess you are not asking how to do a loop, right? Without more details a solution or an alternative will be hard to find. Things like: How many buttons do you want? What would you repeat the same button (same visual aspect, same signal/slot connections) more than once for? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widget can only have a single parent and won't be duplicated if you try to add it to multiple places of the application's object tree.

Furthermore, attempting to add the same button multiple times doesn't make a whole lot of sense: presumably you want clicking each button to do a different thing.

You should instead create three separate buttons:

```
QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
QPushButton * btn1 = new QPushButton("1", this);
QPushButton * btn2 = new QPushButton("1", this); //or likely with a "2" label
QPushButton * btn3 = new QPushButton("1", this); //ditto for "3"

layout->addWidget(btn1);
layout->addWidget(btn2);
layout->addWidget(btn3);
```

Comment: Is there a QRepeater class like in qml Repeater?

Comment: Sory, but it's not a desision what i expected! I need know how to repeate my object!

Comment: There's nothing like that that I'm aware of. You can't repeat the same object multiple times, you need to create multiple widgets. If you have some properties you want set on all of them, you could write a function to create buttons of your certain flavour or something.